# Pulling social profile information as seen in Smartr

Tags: c#, javascript, social-networking

Are there any existing APIs or examples to do this? I would like to pull public social information without requiring users to manually connect their accounts to our website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FullContact API should let you complete the users' public social info, provided you have an email or phone number to pass to it.

Here's the site:

http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/

& the API docs:

http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/

(As others have said, for privacy reasons you need the user to be authenticated when going directly to the source and looking for private data...but for public social information, FullContact should do the trick.)

(& full disclosure - I now work for FullContact - but was using their API for about a year beforehand, so when it seemed relevant to your question, figured I'd post it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however without an authorized user access_token, there are limits as to what you can get.

Try these links to see the data returned in the JSON

**User: (by id)**

http://graph.facebook.com/4

**Page (by name)**

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

**User: (by name)**

http://graph.facebook.com/zuck

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn requires that any calls to the API use an authenticated user, for privacy reasons.